# Meaningful error message if Redirect after Post fails (Testing Django)

Tags: django, django-testing, pytest-django

After successful POST a redirect should happen ([PRG Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get))

```
    response = admin_client.post(url, data)
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

If this test fails, I get a very meaningless error message.

```
AssertionError assert 200 == 302
```

Since the status is `200`, I know that the form data which I send did not validate.

Is there a django-way to get the **error message of the django form validation** into the exception?

Example: I would like to see something like "foo is require" (if "foo" is not in `data`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's custom [TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) class is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` and all of its assert functions have a `msg` argument which when passed are used as the error message when an assertion fails. Also since you want the forms error to be displayed, you can get the form instance from the context and get its errors. Something like this should work:

```
assertEqual(response.status_code, 302, str(response.context['form'].errors))
```

Note forms also have `form.errors.as_data()` which will show the exceptions raised during form validation, or `form.errors.as_json()` any of which you might find more usable. Reference [Form.errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors)

Comment: @guettli Please have a look I edited the answer. change `form` according to your form name in the context. Also look at [assertFormError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError), might be more useful.

Comment: `response.context['form'].errors` ... that's cool. Thank you.